# If I injected httpClient as Singleton and changed the base url for each user request, would I in trouble?

Tags: c#, singleton, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following injection:

`services.AddSingleton<HttpClientFabric>();`

`HttpClientFabric` is something like a bunch of HttpClients, see:

```
public class HttpClientFabric
{
    public HttpClientFabric(IOptions<MyOptions> myOptions)
    {
        HttpClientOne = new HttpClient();
        HttpClientTwo = new HttpClient(); 
    }

    public HttpClient HttpClientOne { get; }

    public HttpClient HistoryHttpClient { get; }
```

I use it in a controller for example. The code is about like:

```
[Route(....)]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(string importantParam) {
    var someParam = listOfImportantParams.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == importantParam);

    HttpClientFabric.HttpClientOne.BaseAddress = _myOptions.Value.BaseUrl1; 
   
    if (someParam != null) {
        HttpClientFabric.HttpClientOne.BaseAddress = someParam.NewBaseUrl;
    }

    var content = ...;
    string uri = ...
    var res = await HttpClientFabric.HttpClientOne.PostAsync(uri, content);

   ... and continue ... but here it's not important

   
}
```

So, the question is if two or more users made a request simultaneously would I have a mess with the base URLs?

Comment: The very short answer is: yes. HttpClient is not safe to have `BaseAddress` (or `DefaultRequestHeaders` etc.) changed in multiple threads.In the case of `DefaultRequestHeaders` it will throw an exception if you try to modify them after the first HTTP request is made. You're better using `IHttpClientFactory` to procure instances of `HttpClient`. They'll be transient and safe to use across requests, but they will share some resources between them to optimise things.

Comment: @MartinCostello thanks! What about `HttpClientFabric.HttpClientOne.PostAsync(<THIS PARAM>, content);`. Has it the same problem if `HttpClient` is injected via Singleton?

Comment: Yes because you're still using a shared `HttpClient`. It's OK to share/reuse them if you're not modifying the properties, but if you need to reconfigure it based on requests coming into your app then you shouldn't.

Comment: @MartinCostello but for `PostAsync(uri` is not a HttpClient's  property. It's just method's argument, right? You sure I can't use exactly `PostAsync` with different URIs for each request?

Comment: No it's not a property, but it takes into account the value of the properties on the `HttpClient` instance.